# Whats wrong? (Type of expression must be BOOLEAN)

Tags: delphi, function, boolean

What's wrong with my code? I'm getting this error:

> [dcc32 Error] Unit6.pas(83): E2012 Type of expression must be BOOLEAN

```
function checkver(): boolean;
begin
  //some code here
end;

function refresh(): boolean;
begin
  //some code here
end;

procedure TForm6.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if checkver() then
    if refresh() then  //Error is HERE!!
      //some code here
end;
```

([full code](http://pastebin.com/dvPNzzHr))

Comment: Perhaps you should consider renaming the procedure. And perhaps making it a method of the class.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`TControl` (which your form class descends from) has [a `Refresh` method of its own](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.Refresh), and it doesn't return a Boolean. The scope of that method is closer than the scope of the unit-level method by the same name because you're writing code in a method of that class, so the compiler binds with the `Refresh` method, not the `refresh` function.

Call `<unitname>.refresh` to get the unit-level function instead of the method.

Comment: Thank you so much, so fast reply i haven`t even expected )